# In WPF, TreeView is having a different outline shadowing that StackPanel with border. How to fix that?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, border

I have a window with a TreeView with a BorderThickness of 1 and a StackPanel inside a Border element with a BorderThickness of 1.
As you can see in the following picture, the Border gets a shadowing effect but the Treeview doesn't. How to fix this (if possible remove the shadow effect)?

[general view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncdh4.jpg)

[zoom view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkg6L.jpg)

I tried setting BorderThickness of TreeView to 0 and put TreeView in a Border , but it didn't work.

XAML summary:

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid" Margin="5,5,5,5">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding FinalResult}"  
                  SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged"
                  BorderThickness="1"
                  >

            <TreeView.Resources>

            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <Border BorderBrush="#ff828790" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="2">
            <StackPanel>

</StackPanel>
</Border>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you might benefit from using the [`UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels(v=vs.110).aspx). From the linked page:

> Gets or sets a value that determines whether rendering for this element should use device-specific pixel settings during rendering.

If you set this property to true on your blurry control, it should align it directly with the actual pixels to remove the blurriness:

```
<Border BorderBrush="#ff828790" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="2" 
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    ...
</Border>
```